# Remove substring from a string

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How to remove a substring passed by variable, from a string, within `for` and other loops (delayedExpansion required) ?

i found a `%%` :

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"
set br=^


rem br;


set "v=1!br!2!br!3"
set v=%%v:%br%=%%
echo !v!
```

but it doesn't seem to work, and it won't work if the `v` variable going to change between iterations (when `%..%` need to be `!..!`).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a `%%`, but obviously you found not all neccessary information. First, `br` has to be used as `!br!`. `%br%` doesn't work. Second, the `%%var%%` notation is to be used with `call` (forcing a second layer of parsing):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"
set br=^


rem br;

set "v=1!br!2!br!3"
call set "v=%%v:!br!=%%"
echo !v! (also: %v%)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use `echo| set /p =` in a `for` loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cd /D "%~dp0"
set br=^


:# Above 2 lines must be empty.
set "v=1!br!2!br!3"
for %%i in (!v!) do echo| set /p =%%i
```

Comment: The point was in removing a substring, /br was just an example

Comment: Removing a substring and remove lf/cr are two different things.

Comment: [ /br | /cr/lf ] is a character that text==string are made of, the question was "How to remove a substring"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an additional example with some `Rem`arks:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Using delayed expansion is necessary for this task.
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Rem The two empty lines are necessary to set br to a new line.
Set br=^


Rem Use the variable named br to set a variable named v to a multiline value.
Set "v=1!br!2!br!3"
Rem You can output all variable names beginning with v with their values using the below command.
Set v
Rem You can output the value for the variable named v using the below command.
Echo !v!
Pause
```

*If you cannot guarantee that the variable named `v` will have a value:*

- *In order to prevent the fourth last line outputting `Environment variable v not defined`, you should use `Set v 2>Nul` instead.*
- *In order to prevent the second last line outputting `ECHO is off.`, you should use `Echo(!v!` instead.*

To remove all instances of the string value of `!br!` from the now existng variable named `v`, you would need to use a `Call` statement to introduce another parsing level:

```bat
Rem Expand the variable named v and substitute the string value of the variable named br with nothing.
Call Set "v=%%v:!br!=%%"
Rem You can output the new value for the variable named v using the below command.
Echo(!v!
Rem However as Delayed Expansion is no longer necessary, you could instead use.
Echo(%v%
```